# How to change character encoding for column in mysql table

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a table with data already in it. I would like to change the character encoding for one of the columns. Currently the column seems to have two encodings. Even after changing it, I see the same results.

Current Encoding

```
mysql>   SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
    -> WHERE  table_name = "mytable"
    ->   AND column_name = "my_col";
+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
+--------------------+
| latin1             |
| utf8               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Changing the encoding (0 rows are affected)

```
mysql>   ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY my_col LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 2 rows because it is two different tables in two different databases.

Do `SELECT * ...` instead of `SELECT character_set_name ...`.

`ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY my_col LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;` is safe *only* if there are no values in mytable.my_col yet.

A table declared to be latin1, *and containing latin1 bytes* can be converted to utf8 via

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```